# WindowBuilder not present in Eclipse->Preferences after installing GWT

Tags: eclipse, gwt

When I am trying to open GWT designer in Eclipse Indigo getting GWT Initialization timeout.

In order to increase the time out I should go to Preferences->Window Builder->GWT. But I cannot see WindowBuilder in the Preferences.

OS - Red Hat Linux;
Editor - Eclipse Indigo

I could see WindowBuilder core components is already installed in eclipse

Answer (score -1):

You can find under 'Window->Show View->Other' some "window builder" panels available (2 in my case).

Now, to see a java class inside/with the window builder, just use the contextual menu on the java class 'Open with -> Gwt Designer'. Then, you'll have at the bottom of the editor view 2 tabs : 'source' and 'design'.

Hope that is what you were looking for ^^

Comment: Auther is looking for preferences for gwt builder, not the design view.  Afaik the preferences are only available is you do a full install of gwt designer.